# How Does Unity Assign Pivot Point Location on Script Generated Meshes

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, gameobject

I have tried to find any information on how the Unity assigns pivot points to object but all I keep finding is threads on how to move pivot points and that it can't be done.  I am creating a 2D game with a background that is randomly created with meshes that are wrapped in empty GameObjects.  These objects are organically shaped but they have a property that returns a rectangle that bounds the object so that they can be placed in a way that they are not overlapping.  The trouble is that the algorithm assumes that the pivot point is going to be the center of the object. What I would like to know is how does Unity decide where the pivot point will be set to so that I can predict how much I will need to move my mesh inside the parent object so that the pivot point will be in the center of the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix:

Try create the meshes during runtime and see if it always places the pivot points at a certain corner or at least relatively speaking the same location.

If it does that you would know where the pivot point is and could take it into account in your code, if you also know the size of the mesh you spawn.

Comment: Ya that was my first thought too but the pattern doesn't seem immediately obvious.  If figure anything out I will post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I think most general and correct answer that I can come up with is that unity assigns the pivot point to the center of the GameObject that you apply the Mesh to.  The local coordinates of the vertices of the mesh depending on how you create them mighht place your mesh so that its logical center is not the same as the that of the empty GameObject that it is attached to.  What I did to fix the issue was to make a vector from local point (0,0,0) to the center of bounding rectangle and translate the vertices I use to make my mesh by that vector inverted. It wasn't perfect but by far close enough to ensure that I won't have any overlapping meshes.